# splitpcap windows tools command in unix

Tags: linux, command

I am using this windows command split pcap into size of 30,000 buffer bytes 
Splitpcap2.exe -r f.pcap -b 30000

Can anybody provide me equivalent Unix/Linux command to do this work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you want but `editcap(1)` (part of `wireshark`) will allow you to manipulate a capture file and include ranges of packet numbers in the output or truncate packets.

Or you can try http://www.badpenguin.co.uk/files/pcap-util2 which I think will do exactly what you want.